# input being ignored, function looping at for statement

Tags: python

I was just introduced to python less than a week ago and I'm trying to make a simple game of blackjack. I've written out the core of the program and it seems that it's ignoring the raw input, and just continually looping through the for conditional. It doesn't matter if what I type, hit, stay, whatever. Here's the code:

```
def main_game():
    number = random.randint(1,13)
    card_type_number = random.randint(1,4)
    total = 0
    dealer = random.randint(1,21)
    input = raw_input("Would you like to Hit or Stay? \n")

    if input == "hit" or "Hit":
        card_number = numberConverter(number)
        card_type = typeConverter(card_type_number)
        new_amount = number
        print "You got a %s of %s. You currently have %s. \n" % (card_number, card_type, number)
        total += number
        number = random.randint(1,13)
        card_type_number = random.randint(1,5)
        main_game()
    elif input == ("Stay" or "stay") and total == 21:
        print "Holy Cow! A perfect hand!"
        main_game()
    elif input == ("Stay" or "stay") and total < dealer:
        print "Sorry, the dealer had %s" % (dealer)
        maingame()
    elif input == ("Stay" or "stay") and total > 21:
        print "Sorry, you have more than 21"
        main_game()
    else:
        print "Could you say again?"
        main_game()
```

I'm at a loss and would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: You should consider using a `while` loop instead of calling `main_game()` from itself repeatedly as the game goes on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if input == "hit" or "Hit":
```

That means `if (input == "hit") or ("Hit")`, which is always true.

Try

```
if input == "hit" or input == "Hit":
```

Or

```
if input in ("hit", "Hit"):
```

Or, even better:

```
if input.lower() == "hit"
```

(same for all the other elifs)